# Parallax эффект для background

Tags: jquery, parallax

Подскажите инструмент , желательно с RU документацией и минимальной нагрузкой , для реализации Parallax эффекта у background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вот такая штука:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Easy-Background-Image-Parallax-Effect-with-jQuery-CSS3.html

Сам пользовался либой jquery.parallax.js, но не могу найти её в гугле

Есть ещё вот что:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Easy-Background-Image-Parallax-Effect-with-jQuery-CSS3.html